# SQL Server 2008 - Binding another column's default value to the primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to know how I can best implement the following simple strategy for row versioning in SQL Server 2008. The idea is to copy the primary_key field to another column (originationg_id in this case) in order to group together multiple versions/revisions of the same object.

When I insert the initial "version1" row, I want to default the originating_id column to that of the primary_key. This is generated automatically by the database, so I'm not sure how to go about it. Subsequent inserts will already know the value to supply for this field.

Example:

```
primary_key, originating_id, date_created, some_value
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1            1               13/12/2010    version1 of object A...
2            1               14/12/2010    version2 of object A...
3            1               15/12/2010    version3 of object A...
4            4               15/12/2010    version1 of object B...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Surely there's another column in your schema somewhere that defines the version row as relating to object B.  If you include that in your question then you don't need to store the first version number for the object.  You can make a view that looks it up and join with the view when necessary without all the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like this is a table that is stored along side the actual data, you can do a few things with this depending on how you are controlling your audit.

1. You can use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to grab the identity value after the insert to the table, and then use that value to do the insert into your reporting table
2. You can use a trigger on "after insert" and then you will have access to the primary key.

If you are doing this inside of the same table for some odd reason, I would recommend potentially looking at a different strategy, as it will be hard to query the "most current" version of this long term.

Comment: Mitchel, I'm implementing something identical. For point 1, can the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() be used in the table definition to define the DEFAULT value for the column or must it be used in a PROC?

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() something that is used at query time, you couldn't use it as a default, as it represents the last identity value assigned in the same scope as the current execution. You would have to manage this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As Mitchel Sellers suggests, I would use an after insert trigger; in that trigger you would use the 'inserted' table for the originating id and possible the some_value column.  The trigger would be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername 
   ON  tablename
   AFTER insert
AS 
BEGIN

declare @somevalue varchar(max)
declare @originalid int
select @somevalue = '<some query to set the description>'
select @originalid = inserted.tablenameid

insert into audittable
select @originalid, getdate(), @somevalue


END
```

Comment: thanks for your post as well - it helped when experimenting with triggers.